# problems initiating multiple threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm controlling a robot and I want to be able to display it's telemetry in the console and also simultaneously accept text inputs from a human controller.

I thought I could do this by using multiple threads? but maybe there is a better way to do it. (still a programming novice)

```
import threading
    def main(self):
            #run initalize function
            ## program should quit if arduino isn't connected
            self.initalize()

            inputThread = threading.Thread(target = self.rps) #rps:Read,Print,Save
            DAQThread =  threading.Thread(target = self.controller_input)

            while True: 
        #### SET UP MULTIPLE THREADS HERE ####
                try:
                    inputThread.start()
                    #Read, print and save the data
                    DAQThread.start() 
                    #controller_input() #ask for user to input control code
                except:
                    print "error starting Multithreading..."
                    print "program will terminate..."
                    raise SystemExit
```

whenever I run this, I get my own error message:

```
error starting Multithreading... 
program will terminate...
```

I feel like I'm setting up threading wrong. any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are the problems that you are getting?

Comment: Remove the `try/except` temporarily and show the exact exception you're getting

Comment: Or do `except Exception as e: print "error starting Multithreading ({})...".format(e)`

Comment: Most of the time you don't want to use a "blank" `except` statement.  Try/except should be used to capture known errors and handle them if they can be handled or issue a more informative error.  Instead, you are capturing ALL errors that can occur in the lines inside the `try`, then issuing an uninformative error.  If you remove the try/except and just allow the lines inside the try to raise their own exceptions, you will get a much more informative error.

Comment: @ForceBru - "(threads can only be started once)". looks like having them in a while loop is part of the issue

Comment: @Frozenglass, this gives you the clue to solve the problem